# Is there such a method call "getBackgroundColor"?

Tags: android, textview

Is there such a method call "getBackgroundColor" in TextView?
if I got 2 textViews: tv1 and tv2 in one LinearLayout. What I did:tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

Now if I wanna setBackgroundColor of tv2 as the same as tv1, how can I **get the backgroundColor** in tv1 first and then setBackgroundColor of tv2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will find the solution here :
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4910bae94510ef77/59d4bb35e811e396?pli=1

It will be something like that :

```
((PaintDrawable) tv.getBackground()).getPaint()
```

Comment: But indeed, if you want to copy the drawable, there is no probleme, a color is a drawable, so copy the drawable as Jens mentioned it.

Comment: This may work if the View in question is a TextView, but if it's a generic View, it will throw a `ClassCastException`: **android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable**.

Comment: @Bourbon How can I compare it? I want to compare a TextView background color with a color like White. How can I do it?

Comment: Hey, that's simple if you use another solution provided by me here (see below).

Answer (score 41):

There is a better solution than bourbons:

```
((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
```

The advantage is we get an integer which is comparable to color enums given by Color class.

Comment: Nice and short answer, but unfortunately for me: ColorDrawable.getColor() is not available before API level 11.

Answer (score 14):

Setting a background color sets a Drawable with that specified color as the background, i.e. the following example will work just fine:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_name);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    t2.setBackgroundDrawable(t1.getBackground());
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution. It should be the accepted answer. +1.

Comment: Now it says, setBackgroundDrawable() is deprecated. Any other option?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such method, because in common there is now "background color" - there can be any `Drawable` object(for example picture). So, you should remember what color do you set for text.

If you can't save it - use `View.setTag()` and `View.getTag()` methods to store any value, associated with view.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
public static int getColor(View v) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
    {
        return ((ColorDrawable)v.getBackground()).getColor();
    }
    else
    {
       try
       {
        Field f=View.class.getDeclaredField("mState");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object mState=f.get(v);
        Field f2=mState.getClass().getDeclaredField("mUseColor");
        f2.setAccessible(true);
        return (int) f2.get(mState);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {

       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```