# SharedPreferences on a Button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to retrieve the `editText` value and the button color using `shared preferences`. For the `editText`, it works very well but the problem is in saving and loading the color of the button. Note that I want to save the current color of the button by `onWriteClick` method and color the button by its color by `onReadClick`.

Here what I wrote:

```
Button btn ;
EditText c;
private static final String KEY = "key";
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         }

//shared preferences
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onWriteClick() {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Editor color = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY, c.getText().toString());
      //Here is the problem 
       color.putString(KEY, btn.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFF"));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            // This call is synchronous and should be done in a background
            // thread
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onReadClick() {
        String text = preferences.getString(KEY, null);
        c.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Any Help please

Comment: you are saving EditText content and Button color in the same SharedPreference location using KEY. Define two tag: TEXT_KEY, COLOR_KEY and save the text using TEXT_KEY and the color using COLOR_KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saving EditText content and Button color in the same SharedPreference location using KEY. Define two tag: TEXT_KEY, COLOR_KEY and save the text using TEXT_KEY and the color using COLOR_KEY

```
Button btn ;
EditText c;
private static final String TEXT_KEY = "tkey";
private static final String COLOR_KEY = "ckey";
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onWriteClick() {

        PaintDrawable pd = (PaintDrawable) btn.getBackground();
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(TEXT_KEY, c.getText().toString()).commit();
        editor.putInt(COLOR_KEY, pd.getPaint().getColor()).commit();

    }

    public void onReadClick() {
        c.setText(preferences.getString(KEY, ""));
        btn.setBackgroundColor(preferences.getInt(COLOR_KEY, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 10 you should use

```
(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

instead of

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: Sry it is not the problem, it is just a typically problem here. I edit it

Answer (score 0):

The setBackgroundColor()-method expects an integer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29

You could use Color.parseColor() method to parse your color string. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29

```
colorputString(KEY, btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFF")));
```

**Update:**
Why are you trying to use a String to store the color? Simply use integer. And use the appropriate Getter-Method. setBackgroundColor()-method returns void.

```
color.putInt(KEY, btn.getBackgroundColor());
```

**2nd Update:**
There is no getBackgroundColor-method. But this question will help you: [Is there such a method call "getBackgroundColor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848383/is-there-such-a-method-call-getbackgroundcolor)

Comment: I tried it but it gives an error Change to putLong or PutStringset

Comment: It is color.putString , but I have to get the color here and I will set it from the onReadClick method
so I wrote  color.putString(KEY,btn.getBackgroundColor()); It gives me error on getBackgroundColor so change to getBackround but I want the color